# output buffering not showing contents

Tags: php, header, output-buffering

I am fairly new to PHP, even more so to the `ob_` functions, so help me understand this, as the manual is somehow does not provide a very simple example or reference.

I am assuming that "output buffering" is what delays and holds php from sending headers until full content is sent, and that may be why the `header()` function does not issue an error if `ob_start()` is declared above. If so, my question is how do I "buffer" only some contents instead of just mentioning `ob_start()` at the top of my script, which is greatly slowing down my application?

#### Example.

```
<?php 

namespace App\Controller; 

class Home extends Controller{  
    public function showHomePage()
    {
        $students = $pdo->query('SELECT id FROM students'); 
        $view->showContent($students); // includes content.php
    }
}
```

//content.php

```
<p> showing stundent by id </p>
<?php 
showContent()
{
    if(!$students){
        header('Location: /404'); 
    }else{
         //show students
        }
    }

}
```

Now you can see in the above example that, as soon as `content.php` is loaded, it will issue `header already sent` sent error (if `$students` evaluates to false/null ) so, to hide this error, I placed `ob_start()` inside my `howHomePage` method as seen here

```
public function showHomePage()
    {
        $students = $pdo->query('SELECT id FROM students'); 
        ob_start(); 
        $view->showContent($students); // includes content.php
    }
```

Now, with the above approach, I get no header errors, but I would like to close that buffer as soon as the `showContent()` method is executed. In other means, I don't want the `ob_start()` to apply only for that following function. I tried to do something like this

```
 public function showHomePage()
        {
            $students = $pdo->query('SELECT id FROM students'); 
            ob_start(); 
            $view->showContent($students); // includes content.php
            on_end_flush();
        }
```

but now, the contents `showContent()` are not being shown

Answer (score 1):

```
<p> showing stundent by id </p>
<?php 
showContent()
{
    if(!$students){
        header('Location: /404'); 
    }else{
         //show students
        }
    }

}
```

This is a terrible way to code. You've already got your output baked in, which, as you've noted, prevents you from changing the `header()`. This is a major driver behind [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), which holds that you need to segment your code and separate your view(HTML) from your controller(PHP). In this case, you've put a function inline with your HTML.

There's a couple of ways to work around this without having to resort to output buffering

1. Do the check on `$students` earlier in the page (like when you get/build the data set) and issue the 404 there.
2. Move your HTML into a separate template file (maybe check out [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) to help with that) and then do your drawing there.

Comment: Thanks, and I know this code is terrible, which is why I asked. But Never mind validating `$students` from the controller and redirecting the page before any HTML content is sent. I understood that, now the main problem is that I can't find any way to redirect user ONCE an html content is sent. So, this means I MUST use output buffering. But, I want to use output buffering only for templates (which contain the actual HTML) but not the entire controller.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by adding:

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);
```

to the beginning of the php file. This outputs everything right away and you can take your other flush commands out.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-implicit-flush.php

> ob_implicit_flush() will turn implicit flushing on or off. Implicit
>   flushing will result in a flush operation after every output call, so
>   that explicit calls to flush() will no longer be needed.

Comment: I don't think I have made it clear. I don't want to buffer the entire php file. I want to start it just before the html-containing php file loads, and close the buffer after that.